# Want to share a particular block or div from my entire page into facebook

Tags: facebook, share

I have a requirement that in a webpage I have multiple block of content which is wrapped inside individual DIV. Each block needs to have a share to facebook button. 
Did many researches but couldn't find a solution. Please can anyone give me a suitable code or idea how I can share particular blocks/content wrapped inside a div into facebook.

For e.g.
I have three DIV in my page and each DIV has share button, when user clicks on any of the share button the respective DIV is shared.

Is there any solution to this requirement or whether is it possible to do. Any kind of suggestions are widely accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out this [HyperArts tutorial](http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/tutorial-add-share-button-iframe-tab-applications/) on adding a Share Button to an iFrame tab - you use the exact same code for your webpage. You will be using the [Facebook JavaScript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/).

At the end of the tutorial it explains how to modify it to allow for multiple Share buttons on one page. You just need to add a unique identifier for each one.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I will go through the tutorials and  try to work with it. Will let you know the outcome.

Comment: Thank you once again, its working properly as per the requirement.

Comment: [www.hyperarts.com/blog/tutorial-add-share-button-iframe-tab-applications] not found.Can you please refer another tutorial.

Comment: @appu The link does indeed work - try it again, it just worked for me.